# How to pause the process until results from the Async calls have come back (I haven't been able to apply the async-await rules properly)?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Although there are many discussions about Async calls on Stackoverflow, I haven't figured out how to fix my code using **then** or any other method.
When implementing the head/tail game (my implementation is not the best way of doing it), I don't know how to stop the process until the results from **await** is back:

```
var headOrTail = ['tail', 'head'];
var player1A, player1B, player2A, player2B;

var startTheGame = async function () {
    let playerOne = await asyncCall1();
    let playerTwo = await asyncCall2();

/****These statements have to be checked after PlayerOne and PlayerTwo are processed, and this is where I'm stuck ******/

    if (playerOne > playerTwo) {
        console.log('Player 1 won!');
    } else if (playerOne < playerTwo) {
        console.log('Player 2 won!');
    } else {
        console.log('No one won!');
    }

}

const asyncCall1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            player1A = Math.round(Math.random());
            console.log('Player 1 first attempt: ' + headOrTail[player1A])
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            player1B = Math.round(Math.random());
            console.log('Player 1 second attempt: ' + headOrTail[player1B])
        }, 4000);

        resolve(player1A + player1B);
    })
}

const asyncCall2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            player2A = Math.round(Math.random());
            console.log('Player 2 first attempt: ' + headOrTail[player2A]);
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            player2B = Math.round(Math.random());
            console.log('Player 2 second attempt: ' + headOrTail[player2B]);
        }, 4000);

        resolve(player2A + player2B);
    })
}

startTheGame();
```

Comment: Both of your `async` functions will resolve immediately, because `setTimeout()` returns immediately.

Comment: @Pointy you're right, that was the problem. Thank you.